# Function inside of (document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am working with a VB.NET site that uses a master page. I have my custom.js file being called in the master page. I had inserted a simple bit of code to test the custom.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function sayHello(){
        alert("Hello!");
    }
});
```

EDIT: Here is how the call is made in my HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:sayHello();">Something</a>
```

When I call this function in my .aspx page nothing happens. However, leaving the code in the .aspx alone and moving the function outside of the document.ready enables the code to run. Ideas why this is happening?

EDIT: I have added [a related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789110/how-to-craft-links-so-they-are-handled-by-jquery-in-document-ready-and-not-globa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you might be trying to invoke the function `sayHello` from a global scope where it is defined in the closure of document.ready callback. So it is only accessible inside that. When you move outside of it you are defining it in global scope and it is accessible when you try to access it in the global scope or any other inner scopes.

> When I call this function in my .aspx page nothing happens.

You must be getting an error.

You can safely define your function outside the document.ready. You need only to place (most cases) the piece of code that accesses the dom inside the ready handler (unless that script comes after the element in the html).

Comment: I use domready events especially when loading javascript from a separate file, or from a CDN/network URL. Use it to initialize objects that help define the state of the page, analyze/use elements in the DOM tree, and catch any errors that would cause the page to simply not work for the user.

Comment: What you say about global scope, etc. makes sense, but this is a call from inside of a hyperlink that is in the document itself. Perhaps I am not understanding, but that would seem to me that the function should then be available after the document loads fully. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelMahony you are missing that info in your question. How are u binding your handle r.  If u are doing it as inline html attribute handlers then it looks for the function in the global scope. This is where u should start binding the events via javascript so this issue doesn't happen. Also this is not about timing this is about scope.

Comment: I edited my question to include how I am calling the function.

Comment: @MichaelMahony Yes that holds true as is said. This will look for sayhello in global scope. If you bind the event using javascript (instead of inline handlers as you are currently doing) in document.ready you needn't have it in global scope.

Comment: OK, so that's the answer. Thanks!